# What are the last three digits of the summation $S=\sum_{i=2}^{10^7} (i^7 + i^5)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

I'd like to find the last three digits of

$$S= \sum_{i=2}^{10^7}\bigl(i^7 + i^5\bigr)$$

I tried to calculate the sum by using partial sums and by process of similarity and periodicity of last digits but I can't proceed with that. I have found that the last digit is $0$ but I can't find the last three digits. Please help me to do it.

Comment: If your sum is divisible by $1000$, then the last three digits are $000$.  If you start from $i=1$ instead of $i=2$ how does the sum change?

Comment: This feels to me a bit like a cute AMC10 or AMC12 problem, or a number theory problem from an early math oriented contest. Where did you get this problem?

Answer (score 6):

The three last digits of $i^7+i^5$ repeat every 1000 numbers, so if the lower limit of the sum were $i=1$, then you would have $10\,000$ repetitions of the *same* thousand terms modulo $1000$. This gives $10000x$ for some $x$, and the last three digits of *that* are obviously $000$.

Can you now correct for the fact that the term $1^7+1^5$ *is not there*?

Comment: How do you know they repeat every $1000$ numbers?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: Because when we add or multiply two integers the only parts of the input that can possibly influence any of the last three digits of the result is the last three digits of the inputs. Using this property several times in a row tells us that the last three digits of $i^7+i^5 = i\cdot i\cdot i\cdot i\cdot i\cdot i\cdot i+i\cdot i\cdot i\cdot i\cdot i$ can depend only on the last three digits of $i$. And those digits repeat every 1000 numbers ...

Comment: Or, for a more dignified formulation, use the binomial theorem to expand the powers in $(i+1000)^7+(i+1000)^5$ and observe that all terms _other than_ $i^7$ and $i^5$ contain at least one factor of $1000$ somewhere, so the difference between $(i+1000)^7+(i+1000)^5$ and $i^7+i^5$ is a multiple of $1000$ and therefore the two numbers it is a difference of has the same last three digits.